# LG Optimus G and Mac OSX

Tags: sync, macos

I just got an LG Optimus G from my carrier, and was extremely excited for it! I finished recovering my documents and such, and then I went to load my music and pictures... But my Mac isn't recognizing it!

I checked my phone, and it was set to just `USB Charging`. That explains it... I tried the LG Software option, but couldn't find it on their website for Mac OSX. I emailed LG Support, and they said their software does not run on OSX. OK, I got another 3 options to try...

USB Tethering wouldn't transfer files... Maybe Media Sync (MTP)? It says that I can transfer files or synchronize with Windows Media Player. I select that, but nothing appears on my computer, and iTunes doesn't read it. Finally, I tried the Camera (PTP) option; this brought up my iPhoto asking me to download pictures. It doesn't let me add files to the phone though.

So my question is, **how can I transfer files easily (preferably via a sync) between my phone and my OSX 10.6 MacBook Pro?**

**EDIT**: I received an email reply back after they told me they do not have their LG software available for a Mac. They told me to try Salling Software to do the sync, along with instructions. However, my phone is not listed (actually, *no* LG phones are listed) as being compatible with the software. I followed LG's instructions, but it did not help (instructions below)

[image]

**EDIT 2**: A friend suggested Winamp for Mac. I'm just trying to get it to properly import all my media, then I will post the results

Comment: What is your Android version?

Comment: @Liam 4.0.4. 15 character minimum

Comment: Is there not a USB Mass Storage option? Try `System Settings->Storage->Menu->USB Computer Connection`. This will mount is as a pen drive like device.

Comment: No menu comes up on the storage menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a few work arounds, although not too elegant.

## Music

I used [Winamp for Mac](http://www.winamp.com/mac), and the [Winamp app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nullsoft.winamp&feature=nav_result) to transfer the music from my iTunes library. I loaded Winamp, and told it to import my iTunes media, waited for it to finish, then created playlists. I can then right-click the playlist on the left, and click Send To->LG Optimus G. The transfer took a while over Wifi, but it moved my library over

## Other Files

I used the Bluetooth Exchange program for my Mac. In hindsight, I learned eventually I could have transferred via Wifi with [ES File Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop&feature=search_result)'s FTP or SMB sharing. But again, this is how I solved it. Bluetooth was deadly slow, but it did eventually work.

Answer (score 2):

The way it works for me is that I use the "MTP" transfer function on my LG Optimus G, together with the Android File Transfer, which is downloadable here:

> > http://www.android.com/filetransfer/

And tadaaa! It works.

Answer (score -1):

Download an application called "Android File Transfer". The application should pop up automatically whenever you set "Media Sync" once you connect the Mac to your phone via the USB. Then, you should be able to drag and drop files to and from your phone to the mac.

Comment: Please provide a link to the app.